# `by` and `.EACHI` in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

```
a = data.table(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, NA_integer_), t = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, NA_integer_), x = 11:15)
b = data.table(id = 1:2, y = c(11L, 15L))

# > a
# id  t  x
# 1:  1  1 11
# 2:  1  2 12
# 3:  2  1 13
# 4:  3  2 14
# 5: NA NA 15

# > b
# id  y
# 1:  1 11
# 2:  2 15

a[b, on=.(id), sum(x), by = .(id)]
# > a[b, on=.(id), sum(x), by = .(id)]
# id V1
# 1:  1 23
# 2:  1 13
```

Why does the above query not return id = 2, V1 = 13 in the second row? I get what I would expect using `by=.EACHI` though:

```
a[b, on=.(id), sum(x), by = .EACHI]
# > a[b, on=.(id), sum(x), by = .EACHI]
# id V1
# 1:  1 23
# 2:  2 13
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that when doing a right join between two data.tables, we should use `by=.EACHI` in the `by` parameter of the join, and not use any variables from the right table (`b` here), as they won't be accessible in the resulting joined table.  Thats why `by = .id` in the first query doesn't work.

As noted in section 3.5.3 here http://franknarf1.github.io/r-tutorial/_book/tables.html

> Beware DT[i,on=,j,by=bycols]. Just to repeat: only by=.EACHI works in
>   a join. Typing other by= values there will cause i’s columns to become
>   unavailable

This query helped me understand the above statement a little better:

```
a[b, .SD, on = .(id)]
# id t  x
# 1:  1 1 11
# 2:  1 2 12
# 3:  2 1 13
```

The columns from `b`, besides `id`, are not accessible in `.SD` for this join.

I guess that means in a join like the above, `by` must take either `.EACHI`, or a column name from the left table (`a` here) that is not the join variable name (as in the question above shows, `id` doesn't work right, even though it is in `a` too).  Because using a column name from `a` seems to work correctly:

```
a[b, sum(x), on = .(id), by = .(t)]
   t V1
1: 1 24
2: 2 12
```

Comment: Nice answer. Btw, another example to consider `a[b, sum(y), on = .(id), by = .(t)]` -- the by= works, but y (from b) is not found.

Comment: On data.table 1.11.4 the following gives the expected output and therefore it seems your explanation above is no longer valid. Would you like to reconsider your answer?  
----

    a[b, on=.(id), sum(x), by = .(id)]  
       id V1
    1:  1 23
    2:  2 13

Comment: SInce I am uable to add a line break in above comment you may have to imagine line breaks after * a[b, on=.(id), sum(x), by = .(id)]* and after *V1 1: 1 23 *