# Concrete use cases of .BY and .EACHI special symbols used in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have seen the following two SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47989843/by-and-eachi-in-data-table) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153174/use-of-by-and-eachi-in-the-data-table-package) and both do not clearly explain the purpose of the two reserved symbols `.BY` and `.EACHI`.

I understand the symbols `.N`, `.SD` and `.SDcols` very well and use them in my code all the time but can't get my head around the real use of `.BY` and `EACHI`. I have scanned all the data table documentation on CRAN but these two symbols are missing in most and at best give a superficial explanation without concrete examples.

I went through this excellent tutorial on data.tables on CRAN [`here`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) and again it misses to explain the symbols `.BY` and `.EACHI`. Can someone please explain these two symbols with real use case. Preferably take the same airlines example code given in the datatable vignette [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html)?

Comment: See several SO links in this open issue: [Add examples using .BY to documentation](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1363)

Comment: I have studied the examples posted on the links and have got a good understanding of .BY after trying it on my own data. Soon I will post a comprehensive answer with what I feel will make it clearer to anyone else trying to use `.BY`. I have deleted my short answer and will soon post a detailed one.  Thanks @Henrik